# I am trying to connect my server.js express api from mongodb but it showing some error i don't understand it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

`Here is my code of server.js`

```
    import express from 'express';
    
    import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
    
    import userRoutes from './routes/users.js';
    
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    
    const app = express();
    const PORT = 4000;
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
    app.use('/users', userRoutes);
    
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/articlesdb" ,{
        useNewUrlParser: true
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("database connected");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Could not connect", err);
      });
      
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log('[TEST]!');
        res.send('Hello from homepage.');
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, () =`enter code here`> console.log(`Server is Running on port: http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

And I am getting this error:
Could not connect MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at Connection.openUri (D:\Vue Practice Project\instant-search-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:824:32)
at D:\Vue Practice Project\instant-search-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:381:10
at D:\Vue Practice Project\instant-search-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
at new Promise ()
at promiseOrCallback (D:\Vue Practice Project\instant-search-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (D:\Vue Practice Project\instant-search-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1234:10)
at Mongoose.connect (D:\Vue Practice Project\instant-search-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:20)
at file:///D:/Vue%20Practice%20Project/instant-search-project/server.js:27:10
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
at async Promise.all (index 0) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}`

Comment: change the `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` in this line `mongodb://localhost:27017/articlesdb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` in this line `mongodb://localhost:27017/articlesdb`